# Using "is" vs. "is over the" when dating old objects

Tags: grammar

When answering the question:

> How old is the moon?

We could say:

> The moon is over the 4.6 billion years old

or:

> The moon is 4.6 billion years old.

Is the first answer grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 13):

One says

> The moon is 4.6 billion years old.

or

> The moon is over 4.6 billion years old.

or

> The moon is more than 4.6 billion years old.

The first one means 4.6 billion years old is the actual age of the moon. The others say the moon is *older* than that figure.

Never say "The moon is over **the** 4.6 billion years old." The definite article has no place at that location in that sentence.